# remarkable identity for complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have homework to do and the question is :
$$\text{Prove that for all } z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus{\{-1\}}, \frac{1-z}{1+z} \in \mathbb{R} \leftrightarrow z \in \mathbb{R}$$
So I started by saying that $z = a+ib$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$. Then I wanted to write something like $\frac{1-z}{1+z}= A+iB \text{ }$ with $A$ and $B$ real numbers.
So:
$$ \frac{1-a-ib}{1+a+ib} = \frac{(1-a-ib)(1+a-ib)}{(1+a+ib)(1+a-ib)} $$
So here is the interesting part: i used the remarkable identity $(A-B)(A+B) = A^2-B^2$ with $A = 1$ and $B = a-ib$ (in the numerator). Wich would give $1^2-(a-ib)^2$.
But why does it doesn't work ? When i develop this, I find $1-a^2+2aib+b^2$ and not $-a^2-b^2-2ib+1$ like wolfram alpha says. Can you enlighten me please ?

Comment: I think you applied your "remarkable identity" incorrectly. You should've set $A=1-ib, B=a$. The numerator then comes up as $(1-ib)^2-a^2=1-2ib-b^2-a^2$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop : in France, the identities $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2; (a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2; (a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ are traditionnaly called "identités remarquables".

Comment: @Baptiste : $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\color{red}{-\{-1\}}, \frac{1-z}{1+z} \in \mathbb{R} \leftrightarrow z \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=1$ and $B=a-ib$. Then $A+B=1+a-ib$ and $A-B=1-(a-ib)=1-a\color{red}+ib$. As @Stinking Bishop wrote, $(1-a-ib)(1+a-ib)=(1-ib-a)(1-ib+a)=(1-ib)^2-a^2=1-2ib-b^2-a^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I like this answer as it is trying to answer the OP's *actual* question "*But why does it doesn't work?*" (i.e. address the mistake in OP's reasoning) rather than provide an alternative solution to OP's homework question.

Answer (score 5):

One characterisation of reals is given by $u=\bar u$ for $u\in\mathbb C$

Let $u=\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}\ $ then $\ u=\bar u\iff \dfrac{1-z}{1+z}=\dfrac{1-\bar z}{1+\bar z}$

For $z\neq -1$ let's distribute and get after simplifications

$\require{cancel}(1-z)(1+\bar z)=(1-\bar z)(1+z)\\\iff \cancel{1}-z+\bar z-\cancel{z\bar z}=\cancel{1}-\bar z+z-\cancel{z\bar z}\\\iff  z=\bar z$

So the quantity is real when $z$ is real.

Comment: if $\frac{1-z}{1+z}=\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$(necessarly, $\alpha \neq-1$) then $z=\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In fact, this strategy works for any invertible analytic function.